# inverse a core data boolean value

Tags: swift, core-data, boolean, func, inverse

In my swift code below the goal would be to inverse whatever the boolean sign is. Right now the code just deletes the current boolean value which is at user1. So say user1 is true when it is inserted in into the function I would like to reverse to false instead of deleting it in core data how do I do that?

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLo

        if CoredataHandler.deleteObject(user: user![1]) {
            user = CoredataHandler.fetchObject()
            print("after single")
            
            for i in user!  {
                print(i.username!)
            }
        }
        
    }


}

class CoredataHandler : NSManagedObject {
    
    
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
   class func fetchObject() -> [User]?
    {
        let context = getContext()
        var user : [User]? = nil
        do {
            user = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
            
            return user
            
        } catch {
            return user
        }
        
    }

    
    class func deleteObject(user: User) -> Bool
    {
        let context = getContext()
        let delete = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: User.fetchRequest())
        do {
         
            try context.execute(delete)
            return true
            
        } catch {
            return false
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
that is simple but replicates your issue.
Currently, what is `user` in your `class ViewController`, why do you use `user![1]`?
`Right now the code just deletes the current boolean value which is at user1.`, what does that mean?
`inverse a core data boolean value`, where is that in your code?

Comment: I know the code just deletes a object but I thought it would close to the deleting operation. I thought the deleting operation can help.